# how to start SCIP in Windows 7 when I want to use GCG

Tags: scip

I want to use GCG's branch-and-price frame to solve a MIP which is similar to Binpacking problem. So I download the SCIPOptSuite-6.0.0-win64-VS15.exe and install it  in Windows 7 and then install the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages which is required. Also I install the Cmake in Windows 7. But I do know how to do next after failed trying the instructions in the website https://scip.zib.de/doc-6.0.0/html/CMAKE.php (Installation information using CMake (recommended for new users)). I do not know where to start to compile. I even do not know whether the installation succeeds or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *compile* the code, you need to download the source package not the precompiled ones, as they don't include the source files.

As far as I know, GCG is not available in the precompiled packages, unfortunately.

Comment: Now I could run examples of  "the tutorial on how to use the interactive shell" part(https://scip.zib.de/doc-5.0.1/html/SHELL.php) through copying the 'scip' of source files into the installing file of SCIPOptSuite-6.0.0-win64-VS15.exe. I find the 'example' file in source files. What should I do next if I want to compile based on 'Binpacking' example using GCG method? Which platform should I choose to compile, Cmake or Visual studio? Is there any interactive operation between the compiler software and the SCIPOptsuite?

Comment: You need to make yourself familiar with compiling C/C++ code. It's often not so simple. CMake and Visual Studio are no platforms - Windows and Linux are platforms. CMake can generate configurations to tell a compiler - like VS - how to compile the source files.